# How to use BeforeMap Action when mapping two Collections with Automapper?

Tags: c#, automapper

When mapping two single objects with automapper, the `BeforeMap` Action is working fine:

```
return _mapper.Map<Project, ProjectDto>(projects, opt =>
{
    opt.BeforeMap((src, dest) => dest.ProvidedLanguage = requestedLanguage);
});
```

But when mapping two collections, `BeforeMap` does not work as `src` and `dest` are of type `object` now:

```
return _mapper.Map<IEnumerable<Project>, IEnumerable<ProjectDto>>(projects, opt =>
{
    opt.BeforeMap((src, dest) => dest.ProvidedLanguage = requestedLanguage);
});
```

I need the provided language for the mapping itself, so I cannot set it after mapping. How can I pass the provided language to the destination objects when mapping two collections?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I premliminary solved it like this:

```
        var result = new List<ProjectDto>();
        foreach (var item in projects)
        {
            var dest = new ProjectDto() { ProvidedLanguage = requestedLanguage };
            result.Add(_mapper.Map(item, dest));
        }
```

I know, that it doesn't look elegant. if anybody knows a better way to solve it, don't hesitate to share your idea.

Comment: I tried to improve my answer, but I have independently ended up with the same solution, haha.

Answer (score 1):

Using `BeforeMap()` to tweak **destination** object is dangerous. Running your code:

```
return _mapper.Map<Project, ProjectDto>(projects, opt =>
{
    opt.BeforeMap((src, dest) => dest.ProvidedLanguage = requestedLanguage);
});
```

will result in a `NullReferenceException` as `dest` object was not yet initialized by AutoMapper. See, `BeforeMap()` works best at performing some tweaks over **source** object, because any work over destination object can be overridden by forthcoming mapping process. If you want to do tweaks to your **destination** object, it's better to use `AfterMap()`. That way you'll have the mapping process already over and the certainty that your destination object was initialized. I'm not saying you shouldn't use `BeforeMap()`, I'm just saying be cautious with it, and use it when you really know what you're doing.

As of mapping the collections, they may seem to be `object` type, but that's just what they seem to be. Put a breakpoint in debugger to see their type is correct.

And you won't bee able to set `ProvidedLanguage` property on `IEnumerable`. If you want to set that property on every `ProjectDto` that's inside that `IEnumerable`, use a `foreach` loop for that:

```
return _mapper.Map<IEnumerable<Project>, IEnumerable<ProjectDto>>(projects, opt =>
{
    opt.AfterMap((source, destination) =>
    {
        foreach (var dto in destination)
        {
            dto.ProvidedLanguage = requestedLanguage;
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The crux is, that I need the requestedLanguage during the mapping so setting it after mapping unfortunately won't help me